# What does w mean in "worg"

Tags: org-mode

It might be trivial, but google searches do not help.

What does "W" mean mean in [Worg](https://orgmode.org/worg/)?

Comment: I would guess "wiki" but you should probably ask Bastien Guerry: I believe he was the one who set it up originally.

Comment: good guess, it do make sense.